# VSCODE command to force content to clipboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a vscode command which would permit to force the content of the clipboard ?
For example a command like this:

```json
{"command": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction","args": {"content": "some text to copy to the clipbord"}}
```

I'm using the [multi-command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) which is great and a command like this would be very handy for what I need to do